# Probability function and distribution function problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Give the following probability function:

$f_X(x) = c*e^{-\frac{c}{x}}+\frac{c}{x}$, where $x∈ [1,10] $

1) Find the value (approximately) for c so that $f_X$ becomes a probability function.

2) Find the distribution function for $X$.

I found the value of $c$ to be $0.8141$

How I did it:

$f_X(x) = c*e^{-\frac{c}{x}}+\frac{c}{x}$

$c*\int_{1}^{10}(e^{-\frac{c}{x}}+\frac{1}{x})dx=1$

$c*[c(e^{-1/c}-e^{-10/c})+99/100]=1$

$c=0.8141$ (with matlabs help)

To find the probability distribution function I integrate

$f_X(x) = c*e^{-\frac{c}{x}}+\frac{c}{x}$

from $-∞$ to $x$ (using the value of c)

Is that correct? Have a made a mistake?

Comment: I have not checked the numerical work. For the cdf, it is $0$ up to $1$ and $1$ past $10$. For the interesting part from $1$ to $10$, we (in principle) integrate the ugly function from $1$ to $x$.  It will have to be one numerically.

Comment: @AndréNicolas for the cdf why from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $10$? Shouldn't it be from $1$ to $10$ only?

Comment: The cdf is $0$ from $-\infty$ to $1$.  And $1$ from $10$ to $\infty$. This is because the cdf is in principle defined for all $x$. But you are basically right in concentrating on where the density function lives, which is $1$ to$10$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ahaaa ok thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome.